# how to validate a pointer using built in functions other than a NULL check?

Tags: c, linux, memory, vxworks, lynxos

During a discussion today I came across that there are checks in the **VxWorks** and in **LynxOS** which tells you that the address you assign for a pointer is from a valid range. This the first time I am hearing about this code like I assign `int *i=&variable;`.

I should get a warning or error which says that In my application I cannot assign the address value to the integer.

Like while I do a NULL check I am only checking the address `0x00000000`. But there can be the case the address might be `0x00000001`. Which is also an invalid case if its an unmapped area and might not be accessible. Is any one aware of some thing similar for Linux or can guide how its done in **VxWorks** or **LynxOS**.

Any ideas??

Comment: I guess you could try `mlock`, which would return an error if it is not mapped memory...

Comment: @Antti Haapala `int *i=&variable` will always be

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function you seek in VxWorks is called **vxMemProbe**.

Basically the vxMemProbe libraries insert special exception handling code to catch a page fault or bus error. The vxMemProbe function is used to check if the address is valid for read or write. It also allows you to test if the particular address is accessible with a given data width (8,16,32,64 bits) and alignment.

The underlying mechanism of vxMemProbe is tied to the specific architectures exception handling mechanisms. The vxMemProbe libraries insert code into the exception handlers. When you probe an address that triggers an exception the handler checks to see if vxMemProbe triggered the exception. If so, then the handler restores the state processor prior to the exception and returns execution to where vxMemProbe was called while also returning value via the architectures given calling conventions.

Comment: Why is that accepted as the answer? The question is about doing something similar on Linux!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Except, if you read the question, the very end is ... _or can guide how its done on VxWorks or LynxOS_

Answer (score 3):

There are several misconceptions here:

- From the perspective of the language C, there's only **one** pointer value that's **guaranteed** to be invalid, and this is `NULL`. For other values, it depends on the context. A pointer is valid when it points to an object that is currently alive. (Note that this is trivially true in your `int *i = &variable` example, as this is only valid syntax when there **is** a `variable` accessible from your current scope)
- `NULL` does not necessarily mean a value with all bits zero. This is the **most common case**, but there can be platforms that use a different bit pattern for the `NULL` pointer. It's even allowed by the C standard that pointers of different types have different representations for `NULL`. Still, converting `0` to a pointer type is guaranteed to result in the `NULL` pointer for this type.
- I don't know what exactly you're referring to in VxWorks, but of course Linux checks memory accesses. If a process tries to access an address that's not mapped in the virtual address space, this process is sent a `SIGSEGV` signal, which causes immediate abnormal program termination (*Segmentation fault*).

Comment: on many systems (including Linux & windows) you can have your own signal handling and not necessary it has to end the program. You may have procedures to recover from those events

Comment: @PeterJ_01 that's most of the time a **very bad idea** and there's no portably working way to recover from `SIGSEGV` anyways. Why bother, if you're sent such a signal, your program has a bug.

Comment: `NULL does not necessary mean a value with all bits zero` according to the standard it has to. It allows IMO ridiculous `if (p)` or `if (!p)` checks.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 wrong again. the `NULL` pointer evaluates to false in a boolean context, no matter what its representation is.

Comment: @PeterJ_01: no the compiler could emit special tests for such cases.

Comment: @Felix Palmen `An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
void *, is called a null pointer constant.66)`

Comment: @Felix Palmen just took a quick look. Where in the standard is this behaviour described? `wrong again. the NULL pointer evaluates to false in a boolean context, no matter what its representation is`

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch `no the compiler could emit special tests for such cases` I do not understand. It is about the signal handler not the signal itself

Comment: @PeterJ_01 exactly in the part you cite. A **cast** is an explicit conversion, there's **nothing** said about the representation of this *null pointer*. An **expression** is entirely different from a **representation**.

Comment: What I mean is that on the few weird [ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture)s (I can't name any one) where `NULL` is *not* an all-zero bits word, the C compiler would emit ipso facto specific code to test the nullity of a pointer.

Comment: Standard does not say anything about use of the lonely pointer in the boolean expressions. Only about two of them. And IMO no compiler will add any code to check it.

Comment: @PeterJ_01: However, `gcc -fsanitize=address` *is adding* code to check most addresses.

Comment: That `-fsanitize=address` option also exists in [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/). But my point is that sometimes a compiler could add code to check addresses.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 then your opinion is just wrong. See **§6.5.3.3p5** and **§6.5.9p5**. Together, `!p` translates to `p != 0` and this `0` is taken as a *null pointer constant*.

Comment: See also the [C FAQ on NULL](http://c-faq.com/null/) (with references to the standard, but already explained)

Comment: And everything to avoid `p != NULL` or `p == NULL` which makes code more human readable.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I state the exact opposite ... very often, a simple `!p` is much closer to the *semantics* of the code.

Comment: And does not work on any ARM Cortex project as the address 0 is valid there. or avr8

Comment: @PeterJ that would be a compiler bug (and would mean `!= NULL` wouldn't work either). If an all-bits-zero value is a valid pointer, it can't be used for a null pointer representation.

Comment: compilers just follow the Standard. in many parts the quality if it is disputable - but of course it is a purely scholastic discussion with no practical use. I someone needs to read the address 0 knows how to do it and what the potential consequences are.

Comment: As always, you just refuse to learn something. If your opinions disagree with the factual world, it's probably not the world that's wrong. Enough said.

Answer (score 3):

In general you can't do what you want, as explained in [Felix Palmen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45840751/841108).

> I should get a warning or error which says that In my application I cannot assign the address value to the integer.

Statically and reliably detecting all pointer faults is impossible (because it could be proven equivalent to solving the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)). BTW you might consider using [static program analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) tools like [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/).

On Linux, in principle, you might test at runtime if a given address is valid in your [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) by e.g. using `/proc/`, e.g. by parsing the `/proc/self/maps` pseudo textual file (to understand what I mean try `cat /proc/$$/maps` in a terminal, then `cat /proc/self/maps`). See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). In practice I don't recommend doing that often (it probably would be too slow), and of course it is not a [builtin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) function of the compiler (you should code it yourself). BTW, be aware of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

However, there are tools to help detect (some of) the faulty address uses, in particular [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and the [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) facility, read about [instrumentation options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) of GCC and try to compile with `-fsanitize=address` ...

Don't forget to compile your code with all warnings and debug info, so use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` to compile it.

BTW, if you store in some global pointer the address of some local variable and dereference that pointer after that local variable is in scope, you still have some [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (even if your code don't crash, because you usually dereference some random address on your [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)) and you should be very [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108). UB should be always avoided.